# Puppeteer: How to evaluate xpath with document.evaluate?

Tags: javascript, xpath, puppeteer

Given a hard Puppeteer task, I have to evaluate XPath in Puppeteer with context node. So I can't use `page.$x`.

I know it can be achieved by Javascript function `document.evaluate(xpathExpression, contextNode, namespaceResolver, resultType, result)`, so I tried this code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function f(page, xpath) {
    try {
        return page.evaluate((xpath) => {
            return document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
        }, xpath)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://personalitycore.com/a.html');
    let p = await f(page, '//p')
    console.log(p)
    await browser.close();
})();
```

And `http://personalitycore.com/a.html`:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>
text_node1
<span>span_node1</span>
text_node2
<span>span_node2</span>
</p>
</body>
```

And run my code:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/xxxx/example.js
{}
```

It just returns an empty object.

But that script did well in Chrome:

[image]

Could anyone please give me some hints about evaluating XPath in Puppeteer with `document.evaluate`?

Comment: Puppeteer already has a method for evaluating XPath: [`page.$x(expression)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.1/docs/api.md#pagexexpression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `page.evaluate()` can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). As `document.evaluate()` returns a DOM element that is not serializable (it contains methods and circular references), it is replaced with an empty object. You need to return either serializable value (for example, an attribute or text content) or use something like [`page.evaluateHandle()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args) and [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) API.